# Error in block header subscription: Error: The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider while connecting the bsc blockchain

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

I'm trying to connect to the binance smart chain in frontend but although window.ethereum do works i keep having those issues in the title no matter what change i made in the code.

My Get Blockchain function:

```
    import Web3 from "web3";
    
    const getWeb3 = () =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
        window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
          // Modern dapp browsers...
          if (window.ethereum) {
            const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
            try {
              // Request account access if needed
              await window.ethereum.enable();
              // Accounts now exposed
              resolve(web3);
            } catch (error) {
              reject(error);
            }
          }
          // Legacy dapp browsers...
          else if (window.web3) {
            // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
            const web3 = window.web3;
            console.log("Injected web3 detected.");
            resolve(web3);
          }
          // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
          else {
            const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
              "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
            );
            const web3 = new Web3(provider);
            console.log("No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.");
            resolve(web3);
          }
        });
      });
    
    export default getWeb3
```

My truffle config:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
    
    contracts_build_directory: './app/src/contracts',
    
    plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ],
  api_keys: {
    bscscan: ''
  },
    sourceFetchers: ["bscscan"],
    
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard BSC port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`),
      network_id: 97,
      confirmations: 10,
    production: true,
      timeoutBlocks: 1000,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
    bsc: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org`),
      network_id: 56,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
  },
  

  
  rinkeby: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/f9b60e17f9254e9cb8fd8bc1bd6cc62f`),
      network_id: 4,       // Ropsten's id
      gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    enableTimeouts: false
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: ">=0.4.21 <0.9.0", // A version or constraint - Ex. "^0.5.0"
    }
  }
}
```

One page in which i'm trying to do some call() and send()

```
//Although i don't think there's issues with this code, here it is

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { CardContent, Card, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { getWeb3, web3 } from '../ethereum.js';
import BALANCE from '../contracts/BALANCE.json'
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 500,
  },
  cover: {
      
      color: 'security'
      
  }
  
})); 

const FeaturedPost = ({web3}) => {
    
    
    const [balanceName, setBalanceName] = useState('');
    
    const init = async () => {
        
        const id = await web3.eth.net.getId();
        const deployedNetwork = BALANCE.networks[id];
        const balance = new web3.eth.Contract(BALANCE.abi, deployedNetwork.adress);
        
                        const buyNft = async () => {
        
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.enable();
        const account = accounts[0];    
        const gas = await balance.methods
        .buy(1)
        .estimateGas();
        await balance.methods
        .buy(1)
        .send();
        
        
        
    }
    
        async function returnName() {
        
        const balanceDataName = await balance.methods.name().call();
        console.log(balanceDataName);
        
    }
            
    }   

    

    


    const classes = useStyles();
    

    return(<>
    

        <Card className={classes.cover}>
            <CardMedia
              className={classes.media}
              image="https://seth-balance.herokuapp.com/BALANCE.png"
              title="BALANCE"
            />
            <CardContent>
                <Typography className={classes.title}>Name: {balanceName}</Typography><br />
                <Typography className={classes.title} variant='caption'>Author: {}</Typography><br />
                <Typography className={classes.title} variant='body2'>
                    
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardContent>
            <Button variant="contained">BUY 5 BNB</Button>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
        

    </>);

}

export default FeaturedPost;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it is clear that the provider you are using has subscriptions disabled. your bet is to change providers to a subscription supporting one.

BSC mainnet has a websocket provider that supports subscription using a websocket connection, you will need to use that instead : `wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443`

Or you can build your own node and enable what you need of services.